# Vertex group, weight paint and Displace modifier

Tags: vertices, displacement, vertex-groups, vertex-weights, weight-paint-mode

New to Blender and can't get what am I doing wrong here. I'm trying to make an electricity bolt using the Displace modifier. I need to weight paint vertecies on the ends of the bolt so they are less affected by the Displace, but when I apply the vertex group the modifier stops affecting the bolt. The bolt is a single vert extruded to a line and subdivided multiple times.[image]

update: here what happens when I try to weight paint the vertecies of the bolt. i can't use the gradient tool and the brush
[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Uncheck the blue button near to the vertex group name. When blue, it means that it inverts the vg effect.

Comment: @lemon yes but he says that he has assigned the ends to the vertex group, so it should work well...

Comment: @moonboots, I think the point is nobody is assigned to the group

Comment: That's also what I think, weird that he says that he weight painted the ends though...

Comment: thanks for the replies! i haven't yet weight painted the vertecies. i was going to do that after i assigned the vertex group. I also wanted to ask if weight paint can be applied to objects without faces, like the one that I have in my project? because the brush doesn't seem to work on vertecies only. here's the file
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=5EXvrVd5" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/5EXvrVd5/)

Comment: To add to Lemon's answer, you can also select the ends vertices, and under the vertex group list click on the Assign button. If you want to decrease the weight, just decrease the Weight value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For weight painting a line, you can extrude the line (a priori along X here), weight paint, then delete the extruded part.

[image]

After that:

[image]

Comment: I had such idea but I thought that extruding edges only paint vertecies and delete them afterwards is a bit weird, there "had to be another way". but I guess that's how Blender works :) thank you very much!